# Drastic reduction in speed when list formation transferred to function

Tags: python, performance

I wrote a code that is supposed to do some operation on a sentence of a file and elements of two lists - `keywords` and `keywords2`. It is as follows -

```
import os
keywords=['a','b']
keywords2=['c','d mvb']

def foo(sentence,k2):

    gs_list=[]                       #####
    for k in keywords:               #####    
        if k in sentence:            #####
            gs_list.append(k)        #####

    for k in gs_list:
        if (k in sentence) and (k2 in sentence):
            print 'a match'
    return 4

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(r'F:\M.Tech\for assigning cl\selected\random 100'):
    for file in files:
        sentences=open(file).readlines();
        for sentence in sentences:
            if sentence.startswith('!series_title'):      
                for k2 in keywords2:
                    foo(sentence,k2)
```

I have marked the part of the code in question. This piece (let's call it BETA) basically forms a list of keywords which *are* in the sentence selected. As a result, future operations have to be performed using only these keywords.

This code takes approximately **47 seconds** to run 100 files. Now I was trying to think of a way to speed it up. There are ~50 elements in `keywords2`. So I thought I am basically running BETA 50 times by having it inside the function `func` when all I need for it is the list `keywords` and the `sentence`. I do have both of these already in the main code so I transferred this part to the main part of the code -

```
import os
keywords=['a','b']
keywords2=['c','d mvb']

def foo(sentence,k2):

    for k in gs_list:
        if (k in sentence) and (k2 in sentence):
            print 'a match'
    return 4

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(r'F:\M.Tech\for assigning cl\selected\random 100'):
    for file in files:
        sentences=open(file).readlines();
        for sentence in sentences:
            if sentence.startswith('!series_title'):   

                gs_list=[]                       #####
                for k in keywords:               #####    
                    if k in sentence:            #####
                        gs_list.append(k)        #####                        

                for k2 in keywords2:
                    foo(sentence,k2)
```

My thinking was that this would ensure that this list forming process happens only once for every sentence and not 50 times like before. This should definitely increase the speed of the code. But this code actually took **89 seconds** to go through the same 100 files.

I am unable to understand why this can take *more* time than the previous code. Any ideas?

Full code -

```
import os
import re
import time
start_time = time.time()
a = open('F:\M.Tech\patterns for gmk_down.txt','r').readlines()
a1 = open('F:\M.Tech\patterns for gmk_up.txt','r').readlines()
keywords2=a+a1
ri2 = open(r'F:\M.Tech\for assigning cl\rules occurence\s\induced two.txt', 'w')

keywords = open('F:\M.Tech\mouse_gs_small_simple_reduced.txt','r').readlines()  # this has the new small GS
keystripped = [k.rstrip().lower() for k in keywords]
c=0

def foo(s, gmk):    
    if gmk in s:  # checking if gmk is in the line
        l = re.split('\s|(?<!\d)[,.]|[,.](?!\d)|;|[()]|-', s) # split the line by comma, semicolon and space to check for gmks and gs.
        filter(None, l)       # remove empty elements in the list   
        #gs_list = [k for k in keystripped if k in s]    # <-------- PIECE IN QUESTION --------       
        for gs in gs_list: # gene symbols

            gs1 = re.split('\s|(?<!\d)[,.]|[,.](?!\d)|;|-', gs)
            gs1=filter(None, gs1)
            gmk1 = re.split('\s|(?<!\d)[,.]|[,.](?!\d)|;|-', gmk)
            gmk1=filter(None, gmk1)
            if any(l[i:i+len(gs1)]==gs1 for i in xrange(len(l)-len(gs1)+1)) and (any(l[i:i+len(gmk1)]==gmk1 for i in xrange(len(l)-len(gmk1)+1))): # this ensures that both gs and gmk are in l, as a unit(i.e. and in order) otherwise it was detecting things like 'beta c' from beta cells
                #  UPTO THIS POINT WE HAVE ESTABLISHED THAT THE GMK AND GS ARE INDEED IN THE LINE                    
                k1 = '_MKKEYWORD_1_'
                k2 = '_SKEYWORD_2_'
                #print gmk
                text = re.sub(re.escape(gmk), k1, s, flags=re.I) # because of this replacement, we dont have the problem of counting r from behind etc.

                text = re.sub(r'(\b%s\b)' % (re.escape(gs)), k2, text, flags=re.I)
                lt = text.split()                    
                d_idx = {k1:[], k2:[]}
                for k,v in enumerate(lt):
                    if k1 in v:
                        d_idx[k1].append(k)
                    if k2 in v:
                        d_idx[k2].append(k)
                distance = 8
                data = []
                for idx1 in d_idx[k1]:
                    for idx2 in d_idx[k2]:
                        d = abs(idx1 - idx2)
                        if d<=distance:
                            data.append((d,idx1,idx2))

                data.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
                for i in range (0, len(data)):  
                    aq = data[i]
                    loq = min(aq[1], aq[2])
                    hiq = max(aq[1], aq[2])
                    brrq = lt[max(0, loq-6):hiq+6]
                    brq = " ".join(brrq)                     

                if data:                     
                    cl(s, gmk, gs, gs_list, data)


def cl(s1, gmk1, gs1, gs_list1, data1): # output will be the confidence level    
        if gmk1 == 'induced':
            if  re.search(r'(%s.*?-induced)' %gs1, br0, re.I|re.S):
                ri2.write('good')

    return 4        

c=0

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(r'F:\M.Tech\for assigning cl\selected\random 100'):
    for file in files:
        sentences = open(os.path.join(path,file),'r').readlines();        
        print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
        for s in sentences:            
            if s.startswith('!series_title'):
                gs_list = [k for k in keystripped if k in s] #<------- PIECE IN QUESTION --------
                for k2 in keywords2:
                    k2 = k2.rstrip().lower()
                    foo(s, k2)
ri2.close()
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: heidi suggested that working with global variables might be slowing me down, so i passed `gs_list` as an argument for `foo` but it still took 90 seconds!

Comment: Instead of worrying about this, you could probably speed things up a lot by converting the sentences into sets which would make membership testing _much_ faster. Regardless, I would also suggest that you use the [`profile'](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-cProfile) module to see where your code is spending most of it's time — rather than guessing.

Comment: @martineau, i am new to programming. Could you expand on what you mean by 'converting sentences to sets'

Comment: He means instead of using a `list`, use a `set`. They are both Python constructs. Here is a reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset

Comment: What exactly is the code supposed to do?

Comment: @Aya: it is finally supposed to find vicinity matches of entries of the two lists - `keywords` and `keywords2` in the sentence `s`. i have not gone into the vicinity match details in this minimal code - but it basically finds instances where these two occur closeby

Comment: Would including the full code (including the vicinity match stuff) make the example code in the OP significantly longer?

Comment: @Aya added the full code. please have a look. I have marked the peice in question and tried to make it more effective as per comments by heidi. i have marked it at both possible locations - in the main code and inside the function

Comment: With regards to the original two examples, the second always runs faster for me on Python v2.7 on both Windows and Linux. What Python version are you using, and on what platform?

Comment: @Aya i am using Python 2.7 on Spyder. it is surprising for me too why the second runs slower

Comment: Well, your use of Spyder may explain why you get a different result to me. Given your code relies on external files which are not included in the OP, it's going to be difficult to provide any additional assistance. If you can provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then you might have more luck.

Comment: If a sentence is a `list` of words, you can convert it into a `set` of word with `sentence = set(sentence)`. This will also eliminate any duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing `gs_list` to `foo`. It's possible that working with global variables is slowing your script down.

Also, consider making BETA a list comprehension. This should be what you need:

`gs_list = [k for k in keywords if k in sentence]`

Comment: Edited my answer with another suggestion.

Comment: so you mean like `gs_list=[], 
        gs_list = [k for k in keywords if k in s],
        gs_list = [k.rstrip() for k in gs_list],
        gs_list = [k.lower() for k in gs_list]`

Comment: I wrote the code as mentioned in my previous comment, it was twice as fast, but gave 0 matches! any ideas?

Comment: No need to make an empty list. The list comprehension makes it for you. I'm not sure why you're doing `.strip()` and `.lower()` seeing as they're not in your example code, but this should work: `gs_list = [k.rstrip().lower() for k in keywords if k in s]`

Comment: actually, `keywords` has entries which need to be lower-cased and stripped. so i tried `gs_list = [k for k.rstrip().lower() in keywords if k in s]` but that gave the error - `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
`. what you gave made no matches, probably because it is trying to match the raw `keywords` entries in `s`

Comment: finally, this worked - `gs_list = [k.rstrip().lower() for k in keywords if k.rstrip().lower() in s]`  but the time taken is the same old 40 seconds(when put in the function). however, performance was slightly better when put in the main code with 100 files taking 72 seconds compared to the 89 earlier

Comment: You should have done `gs_list = [k for k in keywords if k.rstrip().lower() in s]`. But that won't give you lowercase stripped `k` in `gs_list`. Why don't you do that part at the very start of your program? `keystripped = [k.rstrip().lower() for k in keywords]`?

Comment: i took it at the start and it looks good. keeping the list formation in the main  code and sending it as an argument took 35 seconds and doing it in the function took 26 seconds. But the small question still remains - why is doing it repeatedly in the function still taking less time?

Comment: I'm lost, sorry! No idea.